# Does any nodejs template engine support the template inheritance function like PHP Smarty?

Tags: node.js, smarty, template-engine, template-inheritance

Does any nodejs template engine support the template inheritance function like PHP Smarty?

```
{block name=head}
default layout content
{/block}

{block name=head}
if page have customize the content it display the customize content, otherwise display the layout content
{/block}
```

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a12

Comment: jade is great and will support inheritance via the extends keyword!

Comment: take a look at atpl: https://github.com/soywiz/atpl.js -  it is based on twig from php and has full inheritance support

Answer (score 1):

Try the LinkedIn fork of dust.js: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs

It will look something like this:

> {+head}default layout content{/head}

dust.js also supports the following:
- async/streaming operation
- browser/node compatibility
- extended Mustache/ctemplate syntax
- clean, low-level API
- high performance
- composable templates